# Selecting two non-contiguous files to form a sub-corpus in Quanteda

Tags: r, subset, corpus, quanteda

I am hoping for advice regarding selecting two or more non-contiguous files to form a sub-corpus. This code selects 1 file: testcorpus <- texts (txtdata)[2]

If I wanted to form a corpus combining files 1 and 25, how would I do this:

I tried to modify code I found on the net, with the following results:

```
> my_corpus1 <- corpus(txtdata)[1] 
> my_corpus2 <- corpus(txtdata)[25] 
> my_corpus3 <- ( my_corpus1 + my_corpus2)
Error in my_corpus1 + my_corpus2 : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator

>  xx <- corpus(txtdata)[1]  + corpus(txtdata)[25] 
Error in corpus(txtdata)[1] + corpus(txtdata)[25] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator

> my_corpus3 <-c( my_corpus1 + my_corpus2)
Error in my_corpus1 + my_corpus2 : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Any advice is appreciated,

Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.4.1
## Parallel computing: 2 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

corpus_subset(
  data_corpus_inaugural,
  seq_len(ndoc(data_corpus_inaugural)) %in% c(1, 25)
)
## Corpus consisting of 2 documents and 3 docvars.
```

The subset argument here is returning a logical vector where the first and 25th elements are true and the rest false, which selects those documents into your subcorpus.